# Vote progress bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I create a voting progress bar in Flutter that starts from both end, where green extends from `left side in green color` if people voted **YES** and red extends from `right side in green color` if people voted **NO** . I have tried to find in Pub dev and can't find something like this. Would like to know how to create one as most of the tutorial I found, the progress bar only extends from one side instead of both sides. [Something like this to clarify what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0abg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use linearprogress indicator , if you want to add any decoration, just wrap with your custom widget

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  int yes = 8736;
  int no = 520;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: LinearProgressIndicator(
          minHeight: 20,
          color: Colors.green,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          value: (yes / (yes + no)),
        ));
  }
}
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this :

```
Widget _voteWidget(int yesVote, int noVote) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 20,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  flex: yesVote,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: noVote,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(30), bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text('${yesVote.toString()} Yes'),
              Text('${noVote.toString()} Yes'),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```